# How can I retrieve the list of inactive android devices for a particular application?

Tags: java, android

I want to obtain the inactive devices from google for a particular application. I am curios about the url where you can make the request, and the format of the request. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You might wish to explain what "inactive devices... for a particular application" means and why you think that Google has anything to do with it.

Comment: you can use to device id for this purpose.

Comment: When you register a device for push notification, I am expecting to see this device on google console somewhere. if you don't use that device for a certain period of time I expect this device to be inactive so I would like to retrieve a list of those devices and removed them from the list. I want to do this in a programmatic way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these information in your publisher account

in developer console, under all applications in `Current / Total Installs`

Comment: Thank you. I am curios how I can retrieve those in a programmatic way. I am sorry I haven't mention this. This is why I asked for an url.